# OpenCV QR Code Detector gives circle instead of box

Tags: python, opencv, qr-code

I am at an fairly beginner level with OpenCV,and more advanced python code

I am trying to make a QR Code Detector (from an image-not from cam feed) to work. I ve searched on the internet, found a code in order to start learning from it, the code was wrong so I tried, with my limited knowledge and threads from here, to fix it but now the image instead of a box around the qr code image gives a circle with the 0,0 coordinates as its center(change the thickness to 100 instead of 2), and I can't understand why..The code below:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import sys
import time

if len(sys.argv)>1:
    inputImage = cv2.imread(sys.argv[1])
else:
    inputImage = cv2.imread("path/qrcode.jpg")

# Display barcode and QR code location
def display(im, bbox):
    n = len(bbox)
    bbox = bbox.astype(int)
    for j in range(n):
        cv2.line(im, tuple(bbox[j][0]), tuple(bbox[ (j+1) % n][0]), (255,0,0), 3)

    # Display results
    cv2.imshow("Results", im)

# Create a qrCodeDetector Object
qrDecoder = cv2.QRCodeDetector()

# Detect and decode the qrcode
t = time.time()
data,bbox,rectifiedImage = qrDecoder.detectAndDecode(inputImage)
print("Time Taken for Detect and Decode : {:.3f} seconds".format(time.time() - t))
if len(data)>0:
    print("Decoded Data : {}".format(data))
    display(inputImage, bbox)
    rectifiedImage = np.uint8(rectifiedImage);
    cv2.imshow("Rectified QRCode", rectifiedImage);
else:
    print("QR Code not detected")
    cv2.imshow("Results", inputImage)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your display function, you can use `cv2.rectangle`.

```py
def display(im, bbox):
    bbox = bbox.astype(int)
    cv2.rectangle(im, bbox[0][0], bbox[0][2], (255, 0, 0), 2)

    # Display results
    cv2.imshow("Results", im)
```

Comment: Firstly, the code you gave worked correctly. What I dont understand is why mine didn't work, or better, why it gave a circle..As I understood it, the for loop was drawing a line for each "point" of the length of the bbox? Am I wrong? Was the code I found wrong?Cause the code I found seemed like it should work

Comment: I ran your code but it didn't gave me circle. It just drew a blue point at the corner of the barcode. Can you share the input barcode and the resulted image?

Comment: If you change the thickness to 100 you ll see the circle.I trialed and errored because at first I just saw the blue point..I should be more clear in the original post.The qrcode image was from wikipedia [https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5b/Qrcode_wikipedia.jpg]

Comment: if you add `print(bbox, n, j)` inside your for loop you'll understand. the result is
[[[  8  10]
  [355  10]
  [355 357]
  [  8 357]]] 1 0
. n is 1 and j is 0. it only draws one line with (8, 10) as start and (8, 10) as end. so the line becomes a point. and when you change the thickness to 100, it shows a circle.

Comment: also you can add `print(bbox[j][0], bbox[ (j+1) % n][0])` to see the start and end points both are (8, 10).

Comment: Omg.Thanks so much for the answer. So my assumption was wrong after all (about the loop) and the code itself was wrong